Issue with Laravel, Meilisearch, Scout, SQLSRV, and RHEL 7
In my testing environment (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and MySQL), everything works as expected, but it doesn't work on RHEL. When I insert/update a record for any model using Searchable, it doesn’t appear in my search results. However, when I manually run php artisan scout:import, it does work and shows up in the results. I’ve already tried clearing caches and other solutions I’ve found, but nothing has worked.
Another strange thing is that I use Resources, and in the resource metadata (in the API response), it shows that there is 1 result, but the data array is returned empty — the same thing happens when using Tinker.
After this, I tried manually calling $model->searchable() when inserting any record, but still nothing. Finally, I added a new record in the database, checked that no results were returned, and then manually ran $model->searchable() from Tinker — and, magically, it worked.
I suspect there might be some permissions issue with RHEL between my user and the nginx user, but I’m not sure.

Are you have SELinux enabled (can be checked with sestatus command, check the "Current mode" parameter)? Check the same with SELinux disabled (sudo setenforce 0 for switching to permissive SELinux mode).

@IvanShatsky still not working

What is the sestatus command output?

@IvanShatsky
SELinux status:                 enabled SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux Loaded policy name:             targeted Current mode:                   permissive Mode from config file:          enforcing Policy MLS status:              enabled Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed Memory protection checking:     actual (secure) Max kernel policy version:      33
Clearly, I am by no means an expert in RHEL, but any help is appreciated.

Indeed, the SELinux protection layer is running in permissive mode and should not be the cause of the issue. Sorry, didn't know how to help further...
